# Laravel - Functional Testing: current route is not get cleared

Tags: php, laravel-5, functional-testing

We are using Laravel version is 5.0, but perhaps the issue apply to Laravel 5.0+ too.

In functional tests if we call some paths, router finds the matching routes, but if we then call 404 url, router does not resets current route:

```
public function testPages()
{
    $response = $this->call('GET', '/about');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());

    // \Route::current() is not null

    // Call 404-route
    $response = $this->call('GET', '/asdfasdfasdf');
    $this->assertEquals(404, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

When handling 404 we call `\Route::current()` in view composers, and then running tests it is not `null`, but then running in browser it is `null`.

How to reset Laravel state to initial between `$this->call()`s?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to add `$this->refreshApplication()` before each of `$this->call()`:

```
public function call($method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)
{
    $this->refreshApplication();

    if (0 !== strpos($uri, 'http://') && 0 !== strpos($uri, 'https://')) {
        $uri = env('APP_URL') . $uri;
    }

    return parent::call($method, $uri, $parameters, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);
}
```